# Как определить входит ли тип в список параметров шаблона?

Tags: c++

Допустим, мы используем `std::variant`

```
using var_type = std::variant<int, bool, char>;
```

---

Или свой шаблон со списком параметров шаблона

```
template <class Ty1, class Ty2>
struct my_template{};

using my_template_type = my_template<int, char>;
```

---

Теперь я хочу определить, входит ли какой-то тип в список параметров шаблона:

```
using search_type = bool;
```

---

Для этого я пишу вот такую вещь:

```
// Определяет, является ли Ty одним из типов T1, T2... шаблона TemplateType<T1, T2, ...>
template<class Ty, class TemplateType>
struct is_template_parameter;  // (1)

template<class Ty, template<class> class TemplateType, class... TemplateParameterTypes>
struct is_template_parameter<Ty, TemplateType<TemplateParameterTypes...>> 
  : std::disjunction<std::is_same<Ty, TemplateParameterTypes>...> {};  // (2)

template<class Ty, class TemplateType>
constexpr bool is_template_parameter_v = is_template_parameter<Ty, TemplateType>::value;
```

---

И использую это так:

```
void foo(){
  bool in_variant_type = is_template_parameter_v<search_type, var_type>;
  bool in_my_template_type = is_template_parameter_v<search_type, var_type>;
}
```

---

Это работает в MSVC и GCC, [но не работает в clang](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qaTbMzWKo):

```
<source>:16:46: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'is_template_parameter<bool, std::variant<int, bool, char>>'
    constexpr bool is_template_parameter_v = is_template_parameter<Ty, TemplateType>::value;
                                             ^
<source>:23:28: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'is_template_parameter_v<bool, std::variant<int, bool, char>>' requested here
    bool in_variant_type = is_template_parameter_v<search_type, var_type>;
                           ^
<source>:9:12: note: template is declared here
    struct is_template_parameter;
```

Я понимаю, что из двух специализация шаблона `is_template_parameter` он выбирает `(1)`, но не понимаю, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Пропустил `...` внутри `template<class...> class TemplateType`

```
template<class Ty, template<class...> class TemplateType, class... TemplateParameterTypes>
struct is_template_parameter<Ty, TemplateType<TemplateParameterTypes...>> 
  : std::disjunction<std::is_same<Ty, TemplateParameterTypes>...> {};  // (2)
```